# Connection time-out when SSHing, but only on a certain network

Tags: pi-4, ssh, raspberry-pi-os

I'm a student who recently got a RPi Model 4B to learn more about computers and programming, and I had a connection time-out issue with SSH that only seemed to happen on my network. With some help from my uncle, who's much more experienced with this than I am, I added the SSH file and Raspberry Pi OS to the microSD card. Once I connected it to my network via ethernet, I successfully pinged the Pi, and then tried running SSH from my laptop without any success:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ssh pi@192.168.1.191
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.191 port 22: Connection timed out
```

To try and resolve this issue, I went over to my uncle's house to set it up on his network. He used the same exact format, connected via ethernet, and it worked on the first attempt. Once he enabled Wi-Fi for my network, I went back home and tried again, with no success. The Wi-Fi never connected, and I still got the same connection time-out issues as before. After asking my uncle and browsing for answers online, I still couldn't find why this was happening or how to fix it.

Is it possible that the issue is with my network rather than the Pi itself or my laptop? That might explain why Wi-Fi didn't work and all of the connection issues, as well as why it worked perfectly fine on another network. Either way, I'm currently unable to access it through SSH and would appreciate any help with fixing this.

Comment: what does "he used the exact same format" mean? did `ssh pi@192.168.1.191` work for him but not for you? I doubt a pi would get exactly the same IP address on two different networks. How do you know that `192.168.1.191` is the IP of your pi on your network when connected via ethernet?

Comment: @Bravo it was the same format, different IP address, I should have clarified. We checked its identity both times with arp -a first to find the IPs on the network and then nslookup to check the name of each one. And the only thing we changed throughout was the network and IP address. SSH pi@192.168.1.___ worked on his network but not mine.